# windows 10 check if debugging mode is enabled?

Tags: windows, registry, enterprise, group-policy, bcdedit

Is there any way on Windows 10 Enterprise to check if debugging mode is enabled, via registry or any commands? I tried to research on Google, but I can't find anthing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you check if debugging mode is enabled:

1. Type `regedit` into search bar.
2. Go to this key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
3. Double-click this value: `SystemStartOptions`
4. If debugging mode is enabled it should include the port and say "DEBUG":  `FLIGHTSIGNING  NOEXECUTE=OPTIN  DEBUGPORT=1394  FVEBOOT=2670592  NOVGA  DEBUG`

If it's not enabled it just says "NODEBUG": `FLIGHTSIGNING  NOEXECUTE=OPTIN  NODEBUG  FVEBOOT=2670592  NOVGA`

In this picture it shows it is enabled by having the port and "DEBUG" listed:

[image]

Comment: Alright, I get this, but is there any way to view this data in the registry or is it stored in any file?

Comment: Why would you need to do that if you have this?

Comment: I am currently interning at a place which uses OSquery, and I need to use that tool to check if windows is on debugging mode. Only way it seems possible is checking for a debug flag in the registry.

Comment: Figured it out.

Comment: Doesn't "Option 2" show the configuration that will take effect on next reboot, and not the current configuration?

Comment: In msconfig, the options are applicable for the next boot, but in the registry the SystemStartOptions seems to work perfectly. Thanks @AnstonSorensen :)